# Splunk conditional distinct count

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm running a distinct count syntax, `stats dc(src_ip) by`, and it returns the number of distinct source IPs but I would like to create a conditional statement (`eval`?) that it should only return the stats if the count is greater than 50.

Tried something like this, but no joy. Any idea how to make a conditional distinct count where count has to be more than X?

`stats dc(src_ip) | eval status=if(count>50)` => doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The `stats` command will always return results (although sometimes they'll be null).  You can, however, suppress results that meet your conditions.

```
stats dc(src_ip) as ip_count
| where ip_count > 50
```

Comment: Tried but it doesnt work. The results are not showing anything. Seems the distinct_count works but when I apply the 'where' it doesnt display the filtered results.

Comment: Is the `ip_count` value greater than 50?  If not then no results will be displayed.